# Splitting Workbook using filter and creating new file in column name

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Suppose I have Workbook(Report.xlsx) and in that workbook I have different worksheet. In every sheet I have a column name B_Code. Using filter in B_Code I want a separate workbook with every sheet in it.

[Just like in Picture 1 you can see Sheet 1 has B_Code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WN6J.jpg)

[Similarly in Sheet 2 also I have B_Code in it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6XM7.jpg)

Now I want the data of 001 i.e. Ram in Sheet 1 as well as in Sheet 2 in same workbook as file name 001 and 002 i.e. Hari in Sheet 1 as well as in Sheet 2 in another workbook as file name 002 and so on.

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Save a copy of the file before you start deleting. Then, you can use VBA code that deletes a row when a cell (`rngCell`) has a different value than 001 or B_Code or blank.

```
        If rngCell.Value <> "001" _
            And rngCell.Value <> "B_Code" _
            And rngCell.Value <> "" _
            Then
                rngCell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
```

Put that code inside a `For` loop to check all the cells in column A. Since you are deleting rows, start the loop on the last row and move up with `Step -1`. The code that finds the last row (`lngLastRowNumber`) is explained at [Finding The Last Used Cell In A Range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/LastCell.aspx).

```
    lngLastRowNumber = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For lngRowNumber = lngLastRowNumber To 1 Step -1
        Set rngCell = Columns("A").Rows(lngRowNumber)
        If rngCell.Value <> "001" _
            And rngCell.Value <> "B_Code" _
            And rngCell.Value <> "" _
            Then
                rngCell.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next lngRowNumber
```

To delete rows on every worksheet, put the loop inside another loop that is `For Each` worksheet.

Post about any problems you have as you write and test the code.